# Talend, from different XML nodes to the same one

Tags: talend

I'm almost a newbie with Talend...I have an XML file and I have to put its different nodes in the same output node.

This is the input

```
<product>
   <code>XXX</code>
       <telephone>
           <code>telephone</code>
           <elements>
               <element>
                   <item>
                       <value>
                           <type>TEXT</type>
                           <code>value</code>
                           <value>999 999 999</value>
                       </value>
                   </item>
               </element>
           </elements>
       </telephone>
       <email>
           <code>email</code>
           <elements>
               <element>
                   <item>
                       <value>
                           <type>TEXT</type>
                           <code>value</code>
                           <value>info@email.com</value>
                       </value>
                   </item>
               </element>
           </elements>
       </email>
       <website>
           <code>website</code>
           <elements>
               <element>
                   <item>
                       <value>
                           <type>TEXT</type>
                           <code>value</code>
                           <value>www.website.com</value>
                       </value>
                   </item>
               </element>
           </elements>
       </website>
</product>
```

where those `<telephone>, <email>, <website>` nodes are optional.

The output should be

```
<product>
   <code>XXX</code>
       <contact>
           <code>contact</code>
           <elements>
               <element>
                   <item>
                       <value>
                           <type>TEXT</type>
                           <name>Telephone</code>
                           <value>999 999 999</value>
                       </value>
                       <value>
                           <type>TEXT</type>
                           <name>Email</code>
                           <value>info@email.com</value>
                       </value>
                       <value>
                           <type>TEXT</type>
                           <name>Website</code>
                           <value>www.website.com</value>
                       </value>
                   </item>
               </element>
           </elements>
       </contact>
</product>
```

I'm using tXMLMap for mapping the fields, but have no idea how I can export different nodes as part of the same array.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you will need to do a loop on <Elements> in your tInputXML component. Create a new' File XML' in your metadata and set it up to loop on <Elements>

Comment: Thanks.
I guess it's what I ended up with, when I realized I had no chance to do it in the same tXMLMap where I was mapping all other fields.
So now at first I'm taking only those element parts of original xml file, creating the output xml structure and store it in a context variable.

After that, in the full tXMLMap I'm writing that context variable in the final xml.
Thanks!